# using formik in react subcomponent

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I'm using `formik` for a simple form, but I have several multiselect inputs that are populated from remote data sources, so I've made them into subcomponents. The basic form looks something like

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="priority">Priority</label>
    <select
        id="priority"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        className="form-control"
        value={formik.values.priority}
        defaultValue="Normal"
        disabled={isDisabled}
    >
        <option>Urgent</option>
        <option>High</option>
        <option>Normal</option>
        <option>Low</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="myselect">MySelect List</label>
    <MySelect />
</div>
```

Can I pass `formik` as a prop to the subcomponent, or would I pass the `OnChange` method and the `value` as props, or is there a different way that you handle this in the main form object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be simply passing the `formik.value` and `formik.handleChange` as props to the subcomponent and then use them as normal. Note that the `id` of the input in the subcomponent (a select in this case) has to be the same as the `formik.values.name` or the `handleChange` won't work.